# Two arrays comparison with three for loops

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, for-loop

My title isn't the best but i haven't any other ideas. I have one `List` of objects with a `List` categories parameter and one `String`. The String is something like: `"action,azione adventure,avventura horror sport "`. I have to split it with spaces to obtain an array of strings like: `["action,azione", "adventure,avventura", "horror", "sport"]`.
I have to remove an item from the List of objects if his List categories item isn't contained in the array of String. 
I know that it could sound tricky so i'll make some example:

Array:  `["action,azione", "adventure,avventura", "horror", "sport"]`

List categories (of the actual List object): `["action", "adventure", "horror", "comic", "sport"]` **remain**

Array:  `["action,azione", "adventure,avventura", "horror", "sport"]`

List categories (of the actual List object): `["azione", "horror", "comico", "sport"]` **delete because adventure categories isn't there**

Here is my try:

`listaManga.getManga()` is the List of objects

`listaManga.getManga().get(index).getC()` is the List of categories of that object

`String[] categories` is the String splitted in spaces

```
String[] categories = MainActivity.categories.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < listaManga.getManga().size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < categories.length; j++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < listaManga.getManga().get(i).getC().size(); z++) {
                if (!categories[j].contains(String.valueOf(listaManga.getManga().get(i).getC().get(z)))) {
                      listaManga.getManga().remove(i);
                      break;
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

It throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on `j` value.

Comment: What goes wrong? What is your question?

Comment: Maybe is a little inefficient but if your arrays and lists are relatively small then the nested for-loops are not a bad prize.

Comment: I'll update my question @Jite

Comment: @joaquin the first List is around 18000 objects

Comment: It means you need to run the loop in reverse order as you are removing items from that same collection from which you are removing your objects.

Comment: Wow... I didn't expect that the question was an index out of bounds exception

Comment: @muasif80 Sorry but, can you be a little more precise? I think that i haven't understood what you are trying to say..

Comment: See my answer and try that. Perhaps it will work. Don't have your exact environment and complete code before me to review it fully. But have put something that might help.

Comment: Run them backwards: `for(int i=list.length;i-->0;) {...`

Comment: I suggest using a Map when looking up if a category exists instead of iterating over an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following works.

```
String[] categories = MainActivity.categories.split(" ");
boolean found = false;
for (int i = (listaManga.getManga().size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    found = false;
    for (int j = (categories.length - 1); j >= 0; j--) {
        for (int z = (listaManga.getManga().get(i).getC().size() - 1); z >= 0; z--) {
            if (!categories[j].contains(String.valueOf(listaManga.getManga().get(i).getC().get(z)))) {
                  listaManga.getManga().remove(i);
                  // Either do this
                  // i = i - 1;
                  // or put a flag here that is
                  // found == true;

                  break;
            }

            //if(found == true){
            //     break;
            //}
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Wait a bit and i'll check it!

Comment: It gives a different indexOutOfBounds exception: Invalid index 15451, size is 15451 (this is referring to listaManga.getManga() size)

Comment: If listaManga.getManga() size is 15451 as you have said then the i will be initialized to 15451 - 1 = 15450

Comment: listaManga.getManga() size is a variable size, it's not always 15451. But the problem is that also if they are all size-1 as you have written, it goes outOfBounds on the index

Comment: Ok I think i found out what is the issue. After removing the item you are breaking the 2nd inner loop and going back to 1st inner loop. The i is still not decremented, whereas the item at i has been removed already.

So you need to either decrement i before break in the 2nd inner loop or you need to break the 1st inner loop too when you have removed the item, if you want to go back to the outermost loop after you remove the item by running listaManga.getManga().remove(i);

Comment: See the updates i have made to the code in answer. See if it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72931/discussion-between-muasif80-and-fondesa).

Comment: If this has resolved your immediate issue, please do remember to accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it following the inverse loop cycle idea but i had to change the code of muasif80 cause his code take to an issue:
It can get right categories only if in `listaManga.getManga().get(i).getC()` there aren't more categories. I'll make an example: if i have `["comic", "adventure"]` as `String[] categories`, it will find all list item with `["comic", "adventure"]` categories but not also item with more other categories like: `["comic", "adventure", "horror"]`.

I did it setting a new String to check every possibility:

```
String is_contained = "";
String[] categories = MainActivity.categories.split(" ");
for (int i = (listaManga.getManga().size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    if(listaManga.getManga().get(i).getC().size()==0){
         listaManga.getManga().remove(i);
    } else {
         for (int j = (categories.length - 1); j >= 0; j--) {
            is_contained = "";
            for (int z = (listaManga.getManga().get(i).getC().size() - 1); z >= 0; z--) {
                if (!categories[j].toLowerCase().contains((String.valueOf(listaManga.getManga().get(i).getC().get(z))).toLowerCase())) {
                      is_contained += "a";
                } else {
                      is_contained += "b";
                }
            }
            if (!is_contained.toLowerCase().contains(("b").toLowerCase())) {
                listaManga.getManga().remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.s. Also if this is the most correct answer, i'll accept the one of muasif80 for all the time that he dedicated to me in chat!

Comment: Actually I had just tried to avoid those errors by putting in a code to solve the issue.

For the domain knowledge of your application, I have no idea about it.

And yes if anyone can give you more appropriate solution to the issues you had put in the original question, it will be pleasure to learn for me as well.

Comment: Infact as i said, i have posted my solution cause for those who wants to know the final answer to my problem, but without your solution i couldn't arrive to mine. So i checked your as accepted!